# Iterator scope not local?

Tags: javascript, scope

I was just writing two JavaScript functions, one of which took in a long string, looped over it until it hit a space, then called the other function to print the input before the space into the DOM.  The first function would then continue on with input after the space, hit a space, call the print function, etc.

In the process, I kept hitting infinite loops, but only if the string contained a space.  I couldn't figure out why, since all the looping seemed to be set up properly.  I ultimately figured out that my iterator variable was jumping scope out of my second function `printMe` and back into the first, `readAndFeed`, and because of the way the functions were set up, it would always come back as a lower number than the terminating value if there was a space involved.

The first function's loop looked like this:

```
function readAndFeed(content){

var output = "";
var len = content.length;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        console.log(i+" r and f increment")
        if(content[i] == (" "))
        {
            printMe(output);
            output = "";
        }
        else if(i==len-1){
            output += content[i];
            printMe(output)
        }
        else 
        {
          output += content[i]
        }
    }
}
```

The second function is `printMe()`, and it looped over the string, broke it into three bits, looped over each of them separately (not in a nested fashion), and printed them to the DOM.  I used similar loops in it, and I also used `i` as an iterator.

This would loop over strings with no spaces just fine, but if I threw a space in there, the browser would crash.  I tried a bunch of different stuff, but ultimately (by logging the iterator values) realized something was up with `i`.  What worked was changing the `i` in the printMe function to a `j`.

I'm confused; this doesn't seem like how I understand variable scope.  The functions are defined separately, so it seems like the iterators should be local to those functions and not able to jump out of one into the other.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r73y2Lmk/)

Uncomment the "is an example" part at the bottom to crash your browser.  Again, changing the `i` variables to `j` in the `printMe` function completely solved this, but whaaa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't declare a variable, it is implicitly global.  Since you've not declared your loop iteration index `i`, it is global.  If you do that in multiple functions, those globals will collide and one function will accidentally modify the other's variable.

The solution is to make SURE your local variables are declared with `var` as in:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

In your case, you need to fix both `readAndFeed()` and `printMe()` as they both have the same issue and thus they both try to use the global `i`.  When you call one from the other, it trounces the original's use of `i`.  Here's a fixed version of `readAndFeed()`:

```
function readAndFeed(content) {

    var output = "";
    var len = content.length;

    // add var here before i
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        console.log(i + " r and f increment")
        if (content[i] == (" ")) {
            printMe(output);
            output = "";
        } else if (i == len - 1) {
            output += content[i];
            printMe(output)
        } else {
            output += content[i]
        }
    }
}
```

If you run your Javascript code in strict mode, then trying to use an undeclared variable actually causes an error (rather than implicitly make it a global) so you can't accidentally shoot yourself in the foot like this.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `i` is in fact a global variable. Any assignment without `var` statement to an undeclared variable declares an implicit global.

To make `i` local, just include `var`:

`for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know that!